# Changing Background Color and Text Color for Holidays in FullCalendar v3

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm currently developing an attendance feature using FullCalendar v3. In addition to displaying event data, I also want to show information about holidays from the API [APIHariLibur](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guangrei/APIHariLibur_V2/main/holidays.json). If there is a holiday date from that API, I want to set the cell's background-color to "rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.2)".

I have already managed to change the background-color using the following code:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    var dateString = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    // Periksa apakah tanggal tersebut adalah hari libur
    if (holidays.includes(dateString)) {
        cell.css("background-color", "rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.2)");
    }
},
```

However, I'm still struggling with changing the text color of the date number. How can I change the text color of the date to indicate that it's a holiday from the API mentioned earlier?

Here's the full code:

```
<div class="card-body">
 <div class="fc-overflow">
   <div id="myEvent"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guangrei/APIHariLibur_V2/main/holidays.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            // Tangani data libur nasional yang Anda ambil di sini
            var holidayData = response.data;

            // Proses data libur nasional menjadi format yang sesuai
            var holidays = [];
            for (var date in holidayData) {
                var dateString = date;
                holidays.push(dateString);
            }

            // Ambil data acara dari server Anda menggunakan Axios
            axios.get('{{ route('events.index') }}')
            .then(function (eventResponse) {
                // Tangani data acara Anda di sini
                var events = eventResponse.data;

                const modal = $('#modal-action');
                const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

                $("#myEvent").fullCalendar({
                    height: 'auto',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                        var dateString = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

                        // Periksa apakah tanggal tersebut adalah hari libur
                        if (holidays.includes(dateString)) {
                            cell.css("background-color", "rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.2)");
                        }
                    },
                    events: `{{ route('events.index') }}`,
                    editable: true,
                    navLinks: true,
                    fixedWeekCount: false,
                    weekNumbers: true,
                    weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
                });
            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching holiday data: ' + error);
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see on the date 28, the output of cell.css("background-color", "rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.2)");, what I want to change the color of is the number 28 itself.
[image]

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not just use Background Events for this type of event?

Comment: Also why are you developing a new application with such an old fullcalendar version? Version 6 is the latest. It has more features, less bugs, and better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS to holiday dates' text using `edventAfterAllRender` like below,

```
eventAfterAllRender : function(){
  for(i of holidays){                   
    $("[data-date='"+i+"']").find('.fc-day-number').css('color','blue');                   
  }
},
```

Here is live example of it,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FullCalendar 3</title>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var holidays = ['2023-09-13','2023-09-17','2023-09-19'];
         
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // FullCalendar options and settings
                defaultView: 'month',
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    var targetDate = moment('2023-09-14'); 
                    if (event.start.isSame(targetDate, 'day'))                     {
                        
                        element.css('color', 'red'); 
                    }
                
                },
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'Event 1',
                        start: '2023-09-13T10:00:00',
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Event 2',
                        start: '2023-09-14T14:00:00',
                    },
                ],
                eventAfterAllRender : function(){
                    for(i of holidays){
                    
                            $("[data-date='"+i+"']").find('.fc-day-number').css('color','blue');
                   
                    }
                },
              
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Previously, I'd like to make a correction that what I want to change the color of is the numbers in the date. For example, in your response for event 1 on the date 13, it's the date '13' itself that I'd like to change the color to ```color: #e44545;```. You can see it in the post where I have included a screenshot to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. you want to change the color of the date and not the text written below.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now the color of the date is also changed.